# What $\int_0^a x^ne^xdx$ looks like?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Given the integral $$\int_0^ax^ne^xdx$$
I wanted to know what it looks like for an integer $n$ and a positive $a$. After evaluating some values with mathematica, I believe it looks like $e^ap_n(a)+c_n$, where $p_n(a)$ is a polynomial with degree $n$ in $a$, and $c_n$ is an integer. Is this correct?

Comment: I think this identity may help:

\begin{align*}
I_{n} = \int_{0}^{a}x^{n}e^{x}\mathrm{d}x & = a^{n}e^{a} - n\int_{0}^{a}x^{n-1}e^{x}\mathrm{d}x = a^{n}e^{a} - nI_{n-1}
\end{align*}

Comment: It is. And $p$ satisfies $p(x) + p'(x) = x^n$. This means $p$ has degree $n$, and has leading term $x^n$. To cancel out the $x^{n-1}$ term, this means $p$ must look like $x^n - n x ^{n-1} + ....$. You can just continue writing down the successively lower order terms of $p$ by using the fact that $p+p'$ must have coefficient $0$ for every lower order term.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_0^a x^ne^xdx
=&\ \frac{d^n}{dt^n}\left(\int_0^ae^{t x}dx\right)_{t=1}
= \frac{d^n}{dt^n}\left(\frac{e^{ta}-1}t\right)_{t=1}\\
=& \ (-1)^n n! \bigg(e^a\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-a)^k}{k!} - 1\bigg)
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to expand the exponential as an infinite sum...

$$\int_{0}^{a}{x^n}{e^x}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{1\over k!}\int_{0}^{a}x^{(n+k)}dx$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{{a^{(n+k+1)}}\over{(n+k+1)\cdot k!}}$$